# Set the value of an Input element with JQuery is not firing a related list search

Tags: html, jquery

I have the following DIV element:

```
<div class="tree-filter onesetupNavTreeFilter" data-filter="Hola" data-aura-rendered-by="972:0" data-aura-class="onesetupNavTreeFilter">

   <label class="uiLabel" for="983:0" data-aura-rendered-by="975:0" data-aura-class="uiLabel">

      <span class="assistiveText" data-aura-rendered-by="976:0">Quick Find</span><!--render facet: 978:0--><!--render facet: 979:0-->
   </label>

   <lightning-icon class="filter-icon slds-button__icon slds-icon-utility-search slds-icon_container forceIcon" role="button" data-data-rendering-service-uid="380" data-aura-rendered-by="982:0" data-aura-class="forceIcon">
      <lightning-primitive-icon>
         <svg focusable="false" data-key="search" aria-hidden="true" viewBox="0 0 52 52" class="slds-icon slds-icon_xx-small">
            <g>
               <path d="M49.598 45.298l-13.4-13.3c2.7-3.8 4.1-8.6 3.4-13.7-1.2-8.6-8.2-15.4-16.9-16.2-11.8-1.2-21.8 8.8-20.6 20.7.8 8.6 7.6 15.7 16.2 16.9 5.1.7 9.9-.7 13.7-3.4l13.3 13.3c.6.6 1.5.6 2.1 0l2.1-2.1c.6-.6.6-1.6.1-2.2zm-41.6-24.4c0-7.1 5.8-12.9 12.9-12.9 7.1 0 12.9 5.8 12.9 12.9 0 7.1-5.8 12.9-12.9 12.9-7.1 0-12.9-5.7-12.9-12.9z" fill-rule="evenodd"></path>
            </g>
         </svg>
      </lightning-primitive-icon>
   </lightning-icon>

   <div data-aura-rendered-by="987:0" class="uiInput uiInputSearch uiInput--custom" data-aura-class="uiInput uiInputSearch uiInput--custom">
      <input class="filter-box input" type="search" aria-describedby="" placeholder="Quick Find" id="983:0" data-aura-rendered-by="988:0" data-interactive-lib-uid="3"><!--render facet: 989:0-->
   </div>

   <!--render facet: 992:0-->

</div>
```

There is an INPUT element and a data-filter attribute that are set with JQuery.

`<input class="filter-box input" type="search" aria-describedby="" placeholder="Quick Find" id="983:0" data-aura-rendered-by="988:0" data-interactive-lib-uid="3">`

`<div class="tree-filter onesetupNavTreeFilter" data-filter="Hola" data-aura-rendered-by="972:0" data-aura-class="onesetupNavTreeFilter">`

The problem is that this INPUT when is fullfilled by the user (there is not a submit button, just the input) automatically fires a filtered search in a related UL list (this event is defined by the provider of the website, I cannot edit it).

I have been trying to use the following Jquery snippets, but they just set the value in the searchbox, the UL list is not filtered (only when I manually press enter the event fires and the list is filtered):

```
var aux = $("#split-left");
aux.find("div.tree-filter.onesetupNavTreeFilter").find("input.filter-box").val("Hola");
aux.find("div.tree-filter.onesetupNavTreeFilter").find("input.filter-box").trigger("change");
aux.find("div.tree-filter.onesetupNavTreeFilter").attr("value", "Hola");
aux.find("div.tree-filter.onesetupNavTreeFilter").attr("value", "Hola").trigger("change");
aux.find("div.tree-filter.onesetupNavTreeFilter").find("input.filter-box").text("Hola")
```

Any suggestion with this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure "change" is propper trigger event for the filtering script?

Comment: I don't know how the filtering script is implemented. I just know that the UL list is updated when the user manually write the word or copy/paste it.